# AWS Cognito: developer authenticated identities problem in log in and refresh token

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

I implemented a social network app that uses Cognito for refreshing token. But still, I can't get my new tokens. When I first log-in to my server and get my first ID and token from it, The token expires after a while and I can't get any token. This is my implementation:

```
class DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider : AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper {
    override func token() -> AWSTask<NSString> {
        self.identityId = ProfileDAL.shared.getId()
        return AWSTask(result: NSString(string: ProfileDAL.shared.getToken()))
    }

    override func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        return super.logins()
    }
}
```

I put this lines in my `viewDidLoad` right after getting first token from my server

```
let devAuth = DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider(regionType: MY_REGION, identityPoolId: MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, useEnhancedFlow: true, identityProviderManager:nil)
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: MY_REGION, identityProvider:devAuth)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: MY_REGION, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

and right after them, I use bellow lines to get my tokens:

```
AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens { (tokens, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting token \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let tokens = tokens {
                print(tokens.accessToken!.tokenString!)
            }
        }
```

finally I can't get my new tokens and it gives me this error:

```
AWSMobileClientError
  ▿ notSignedIn : 1 element
    - message : "User is not signed in, please sign in to use this API."
```